# Search ability within Watch in debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, watch

Just wondering if there is the ability to search while in watch?  Instead of going through a million tree nodes, if I could simply search for the result and then it opens up the tree accordingly?

Just wondering if something like this is possible? (and if not, why not?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible in Visual Studio currently.  There is no technical reason this can't be done though and has been suggested several times.  I would encourage you to file a bug on connect in order to help make this a feature in the future

- http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: man that would make my life so much easier... also I filed a bug :) hopefully VS 2012?